# Multiply single Elements of a List with each other in specific ways

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a problem with one code and hope that you can help me with that.

I have a list which looks like the following

```
List = {a, b, c, d, e}
```

the desired result is a new list with

```
{a, a*b, a*b*c, a*b*c*d, a*b*c*d*e}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like `Fold[Times, 1, list]`? Also `List` is a built-in symbol, so don't use it as a variable. Stick to variables starting with lower-case letters.

Comment: @J.M. your command returns abcde. The OP asks that this is the final element of the new list created by multiplication of the elements of the original ones.

Comment: Oops, that should be `FoldList[]` and not `Fold[]`; thanks @Darth!

Comment: @J.M.isinlimbo that's the trick, yes. I tried to do it using Nest, NestList and failed spectacularly :-)

Comment: `FoldList[Times, {a, b, c, d,e}]`

Answer (score 4):

Accumulate takes the sum of the terms: this can be changed to the product of by changing the Plus to Times:

```
 list = {a, b, c, d, e};
 Accumulate@list /. Plus -> Times
 {a, a b, a b c, a b c d, a b c d e}
```

Comment: Alternatively `Block[{Plus = Times}, Accumulate@list]` if you don't want to use replacements.

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};
E^Accumulate[Log[list]]
```

Since `Accumulate` equals `Rest[FoldList[Plus,0,list]]` , So `Foldlist` also works.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an operator version of @JM's suggestion in the comments:

```
list = {a, b, c, d, e};

FoldList[Times] @ list
```

> {a, a b, a b c, a b c d, a b c d e}

Answer (score 1):

Another:

```
ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d,e}, { x__,___} :> Times@x ]
```

> {a, a b, a b c, a b c d, a b c d e}

Comparing:

```
ReplaceList[{a, b, c, d,e}, { x__,___} :> Times@x ] == FoldList[Times] @ {a, b, c, d,e}
```

> True